# How to merge pandas dataframes bit by bit in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering how i can do the following merge? 
I have a larger dataframe (newauthdf), which consists of Nodes and Years (from 1990-2000). I'd like to calculate eigenvector centrality for each of these nodes *conditioned upon* the year.So the node 'Bill Clinton" will have a different centrality in 1990 versus 2000. My implementation is below, but I keep getting 'cannot create Block manager with duplicate items set'. From reading stackoverflow, it seems like this error is created because of redundant columns. I don't want the merge to create new columns for each year-centrality merge, but rather add to the existing column. Is the best way to deal with this to just create the complete eigenvector dataframe at once AND THEN merge with my newauthdf?

```
for i, obj in enumerate(nolist):
if i == 0:
    bet = nx.eigenvector_centrality(obj[1])
    sortedeigdf = pd.DataFrame(bet.items(), columns = ['Name', 'EigCentrality']).sort(columns=['Name'], ascending = True)
    sortedeigdf['Year'] = obj[0]
    newdf = pd.merge(newauthdf, sortedeigdf, on= ['Name', 'Year']).reset_index(drop=True)
if i > 0:
    bet = nx.eigenvector_centrality(obj[1])
    sortedeigdf = pd.DataFrame(bet.items(), columns = ['Name', 'EigCentrality']).sort(columns=['Name'], ascending = True)
    sortedeigdf['Year'] = obj[0]
    newdf = pd.merge(newdf, sortedeigdf, on= ['Name', 'Year'], how = 'right').reset_index(drop=True)
```

UPDATE: I was able to get what I wanted to work by doing my suggestion.
I simply created one entire dataframe first by appending each year's centralities and then merged. It seems to work fine. Let me know if there are ways to improve my code's efficiency.

```
ceigdf = pd.DataFrame()
for i, obj in enumerate(nolist):
try:
    bet = nx.eigenvector_centrality(obj[1])
    sortedeigdf = pd.DataFrame(bet.items(), columns = ['Name', 'EigCentrality']).sort(columns=['Name'], ascending = True)
    sortedeigdf['Year'] = obj[0]
    ceigdf = ceigdf.append(sortedeigdf)
except:
    sortedeigdf = pd.DataFrame()
    sortedeigdf['EigCentrality'] = np.nan
    sortedeigdf['Year'] = obj[0]
    ceigdf = ceigdf.append(sortedeigdf)
```

Comment: instead of appending one-at-a-time, append the created dataframes to a list, then at the end ``df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)`` will give you the result

Comment: I see, I like that idea. Is that more efficient?

Comment: yep otherwise u end up copying data each time